# I cannot think of the logics for decryption

Tags: java, arrays, encryption

So what do I write in my decryption block? Any ideas? I have to make a program that encrypts whatever the user inputs and decrypts it as well. This syntax is a stepping stone, for I wil add the scanner and System inputs later. I just want to make sure the methods work when I use them in my print statements.

```
public class KeysLocks {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String message = "super saiyan";
        System.out.println("message: " + message);

        String encryption = encrypt(message);
        System.out.println("encryption: " + encryption);

        String decryption = decrypt(message);
        System.out.println("decryption: " + decryption);


    }

    private static String encrypt(String message) {
        String key = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz";
        String lock = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";

        String encrypted_sentence = "";
        char phrase[] = message.toCharArray(); 

        for(int i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++){
            int geasse = key.indexOf(phrase[i]);
            encrypted_sentence += lock.charAt(geasse);
        }
        return encrypted_sentence;
    }

    private static String decrypt(String message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: it seems that you already wrote something in your decryption block. Although it is not a cryptographically secure algorithm I'm assuming you're just playing.. Were you looking for the corresponding encryption then?

Comment: Are you asking for an encryption scheme?

Comment: The result of an encryption, and the argument to a decryption, is a byte[], not a a String. String is not a container for binary data. And why is the result of decryption named 'encrypted_sentence'?

Comment: wow i accidentally put the syntax in decrypt() not encrypt()

Comment: I've answered as comprehensively as possible. Add a comment if you need further help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Assumptions I'm going to make***

- When you say Decrypt, you mean Encrypt. (although I'll show how they can be the same)
- You don't know all that much about Cryptographic terms.
- You've made some mistakes, so I'll be correcting them a long the way.

What you have written is effectively known as an `s-box`. This is a substitution box that replaces a letter with another letter, and is designed to obfuscate the relationship between the plaintext and the ciphertext. Your `s-box` looks like this:

```
SBOX = {q,w,e,r,t,y...m}
```

And you're mapping the input's text to the character input, so to get it to decrypt, you'll need to perform the same operation but in reverse.

```
SBOX^-1 = "Something"
```

Now we need to work out how to reverse the mapping, so let's start from the beginning. If I encrypt an `a` with your `s-box`, it will give me a `q`. So in your decryption `s-box`, `q` should map to `a`, and the best way to do that is to put `a` in the `q` position. So we know it looks something like:

```
SBOX^-1 = {null, null, null ..., a, null, null... }
```

Now let's move to b. We encrypt `b` and we get `w`. So let's put `b` in the `w` position.

```
SBOX^-1 = {null, null, null ..., a, null, null... ,b, null, null}
```

And you build up the picture from there. When decrypting, you use the same `key` (although in this context I'm not sure this is an accurate name) and you use the exact same method as you used to `encrypt`, just with a different `s-box`, or in your program, `lock`.

***Notes on your code in general***

- When asking a question, try to write your code in english. Words like `geasse` don't mean anything, and don't help to easily convey the meaning behind your code.
- When creating a `String`, appending inside of a loop is an extremely inefficient method of achieving this. You should be looking into the `StringBuilder` class, to create `String` objects dynamically.

***Extra Reading***

- Have a read about [substitution boxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-box). This will explain the concept you're trying to convey.
- Read about the basics of encryption. I found [this](http://www.cryptographyworld.com/) to be a very good resource when I was learning about these ideas.
- Finally, the `StringBuilder` class. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) is a very good tutorial, provided by *Oracle* themselves, to explain how the `StringBuilder` class is used, and more importantly, *why* you should be using it over appending.

Comment: I honestly do not know why my professor gave us this assignment. It is not basic at all and is very frustrating to deal with.

Comment: It's okay, you just need to take a minute and think about it. Where are you stuck?

Comment: The part where I have to use my SBOX in my decryption block. Can we go to chat I really need a walkthrough man